# Microsoft Teams incorrect conversation information data

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm working on teams bot project and i've found an issue with the IOS devices.
When IOS user sends a message to our bot we receive correct conversation information data from Microsoft service and we can reply to a client using that information.
We have next flow:

1. User requests card.
2. User clicks on the card to open task module window.

When IOS user requests the card we receive a correct conversation information from the service:

```
  "conversation" : {
    "group" : true,
    "isGroup" : true,
    "conversationType" : "channel",
    "tenantId" : "5df.....-....-....-....-.........656",
    "id" : "19:6ff255c919a34641b7d2fb59df150ebf@thread.skype;messageid=1589553462779"
  }
```

Next we reply to user using that conversation information with the card which contains task module button.
IOS User clicks on that button and we receive incorrect conversation information data from service:

```
  "conversation" : {
    "group" : false,
    "isGroup" : false,
    "tenantId" : "5df.....-....-....-....-.........656",
    "id" : "29:16qvJAfN2glqz_YAypLR2db_gjXvdZwtM-Au5-Gnd7y-GgLV0jVR8xyYcT6COQHcvMnjLDE6wQmlNRaUnW-x_iQ"
  }
```

We performed all actions above in the same channel but we received different channel information. Also with that incorrect channel information we can't reply to a user.
As you can see:

```
 "group": false  # is incorrect
 "isGroup" : false . # is incorrect
 "tenantId" : "5df.....-....-....-....-.........656"  # is correct, the same value
 "id" : "29:16qvJAfN2glqz_YAypLR2db_gjXvdZwtM-Au5-Gnd7y-GgLV0jVR8xyYcT6COQHcvMnjLDE6wQmlNRaUnW-x_iQ" . # is incorrect
```

looks inconsistent. Other platforms are working fine (android, desktop, browser).

Bot was built on java and we use these libs:

```
 com.microsoft.bot:bot-connector:4.6.0
 com.microsoft.bot:bot-integration-core:4.6.0
 com.microsoft.bot:bot-schema:4.6.0
 com.microsoft.bot:bot-builder:4.6.0
```

From this source:
https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-java

Comment: we could reproduce the issue on our side. Raised a bug

Comment: still happening

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately this is a bug with task/fetch button actions sent by a bot, in the current version of the iOS Teams app. We have a fix ready, and it will be available with the next release.

Comment: @Oleksa, Are you able to verify the fix ?

Comment: not, didn't fix. I am suffering same problem then search engine led me here.

Comment: Well we did workaround But it seems we don't have such issues at the moment.
So yeah i guess it was fixed. You need to try to update your Teams apps. Hope this will help.